# Advise on Haskell testing framework suitable for functions interacting with (SQLite) databases

Tags: database, sqlite, unit-testing, haskell

My project is a data manager library which among other things feature a parser of a DSL that generates SQL queries that are semantically given an SQL database schema, using SQLite as for storage. Parts of the testing code then need the database to be set up (scaffolding) to provide the specific scenario in the database within which I need to test for the function in terms of assertions on output.

Are there testing frameworks for Haskell that are better or worse for this, you think? I thought I'd  ask for advise first before I spend too much time learning the different frameworks out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I think the major testing frameworks in Haskell are equally suited for this. For persistent, I use hspec, and have no complaints. Many people also use tasty, and that seems to work out well too. I honestly can't give you a list of advantages and disadvantages between the two, I'd recommend looking into them and making a decision.

The other two players I'm aware of are HTF and test-framework. I don't know anything about HTF, but AFAIK, test-framework is essentially superseded by tasty.

I believe all of these frameworks work well with both HUnit and QuickCheck.

Comment: Don't miss out HSpecs automatic test discovery feature (but AFAIK you can use HSpec from tasty - I just don't know if the discovery works too n this scenario)